Start Retrieving from the middle of MySQL table
I have a MySQL table and want to start retrieving from the middle of the table, but I don't have a unique ID and don't want to retrieve all of the columns. When I start retrieving the query will start from the first row.



Colum A
Colum B
Colum C




12364
CC
4785457


88364
AR
6874688


12774
BB
6847854


19864
VV
4768558


17482
MM
5835738


27549
TT
5764866



I want to start retrieving from the third row, the columns to retrieve are B and C.

In relational databases, there is no such concept as "beginning" or "end" or "middle" of a table. You MUST define an ORDER BY for the table to get this. You can use any column (or columns) you want for this, but you MUST do it and it must be fully deterministic (no ties allowed) or you can get different results from different runs of the same query on the same data.

Will your table always have 6 rows?

@kmoser No, it's more than 500000

@JoelCoehoorn How can I determine the ORDER BY when I don't have sequenced values?

How do you define this “middle”?  Whatever filtering and ordering you want to use would need to be specified in the query.

@Rena That's something you have to think about when designing the table! Maybe there are other columns (a datetime?) you can look at. But again: until you can do this, the database is free to return different results for different runs of the same query on the same data.

What the middle is completely depends on the order.  It's not a spreadsheet.

on version 8.x  ... will something along the following help?:  SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as rownum FROM your-table-name ) rowids WHERE rownum > (SELECT COUNT(*)/2 FROM your-table-name );

As already commented, it couldn't meet the expectations (whatever expected it is) without an order by of some kind. You just couldn't know what the resultset could be.
Here is a sample without Order By and two samples with different Order By...
WITH      --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (col_a, col_b, col_c) AS
      ( Select 12364,   'CC',   4785457 Union All
        Select 88364,   'AR',   6874688 Union All
        Select 12774,   'BB',   6847854 Union All
        Select 19864,   'VV',   4768558 Union All
        Select 17482,   'MM',   5835738 Union All
        Select 27549,   'TT',   5764866
     )

Without a proper Order By clause in Row_Number() Over() analytic function your resultset  could be different every time you run the query.
Sample 1 - no Order By clause - in Row_number() Over() analytic function -  ( result is unpredictable )
SELECT t.col_b, t.col_c
FROM ( Select Row_Number() Over() as rn, Count(*) Over() as cnt, col_b, col_c
       From   tbl ) t
WHERE  t.rn >= Floor( t.cnt / 2 )
ORDER BY rn

/*   R e s u l t : 
col_b      col_c
-----   --------
BB       6847854
VV       4768558
MM       5835738
TT       5764866      */

With Order By clause in Row_Number() Over() analytic function your resultset  is more convenient.
Sample 2 - Order By clause - Row_number() Over(Order By col_b) analytic function
SELECT t.col_b, t.col_c
FROM ( Select Row_Number() Over(Order By col_b) as rn, Count(*) Over() as cnt, col_b, col_c
       From   tbl ) t
WHERE  t.rn >= Floor( t.cnt / 2 )
ORDER BY rn

/*    R e s u l t :
col_b      col_c
-----   --------
CC       4785457
MM       5835738
TT       5764866
VV       4768558    */

With Order By another column values in Descending order ...
Sample 3 - Order By clause - Row_number() Over(Order By col_c Desc) analytic function
SELECT t.col_b, t.col_c
FROM ( Select Row_Number() Over(Order By col_c Desc) as rn, Count(*) Over() as cnt, col_b, col_c
       From   tbl ) t
WHERE  t.rn >= Floor( t.cnt / 2 )
ORDER BY rn

/*    R e s u l t :
col_b      col_c
-----   --------
MM       5835738
TT       5764866
CC       4785457
VV       4768558   */

See the fiddle here.
